# remove double quotes from first element of the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to remove double quotes from this list:

```
>>> a
["6/1, 0, 0, ['79', '80', '81', '82']"]
```

I tried converting first element of list to list which is a string but dint work:

```
>>> a[0]
"6/1, 0, 0, ['79', '80', '81', '82']"

>>> list(a[0])
['6', '/', '1', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '[', "'", '7', '9', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '8', '0', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '8', '1', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '8', '2', "'", ']']
```

Expected output:

```
>>> a
[6/1, 0, 0, ['79', '80', '81', '82']]
                    or
>>> a
['6/1', '0', '0', ['79', '80', '81', '82']]
```

Can someone please help me resolving this issue?

Comment: It isn't possible to output 6/1 if it's not contained in a string

Comment: `a` is a list of one element, a string containing nested structures and domain-specific data types (`6/1`). It's a mess to try to parse this in any sensible way and you should fix this on the generating side instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will evaluate the string as a list:

`a = list(eval(a[0]))`

`[6, 0, 0, ['79', '80', '81', '82']]`

If you know your port will be 6/1, you can replace it with a string like this:

```
a = list(eval(a[0]))
a[0] = '6/1'
```

`['6/1', 0, 0, ['79', '80', '81', '82']]`

If your port is going to change, but you know it will always be the first element, you can do this:

`a = list(eval("'" + a[0].split(',')[0] + "'" + "," + ','.join(a[0].split(',')[1:])))`

`['6/1', 0, 0, ['79', '80', '81', '82']]`

Or cleaner version:

```
l = a[0].split(',')
a = list(eval("'" + l[0] + "' ," + ','.join(l[1:])))
```

`['6/1', 0, 0, ['79', '80', '81', '82']]`

Comment: But that is removing `6/1` and this is the output: `[6, 0, 0, ['79', '80', '81', '82']]`

Comment: What is 6/1? If it's a string then it should be represented as '6/1', if not then it's equivalent to 6.

Comment: but what do you want `6/1` to be? A string containing 3 characters (`6`, `/` and `1`)? There is a Fraction library in python if you want this to be a number, and storing fractions matters to you. Otherwise, 6/1 is 6.

Comment: `6/1` is my port, can't change it to anything else.

Comment: @Sweety So why not have as a string?

Comment: It would do if I get `6/1` as string in the final output like this: ['6/1', 0, 0, ['79', '80', '81', '82']]

Comment: But how will I get `6/1` back once it changes it to `6`? As it can be different ports, not just 1. It can be `6/1`, `6/2`, `6/3`, `6/4` like wise.

Answer (score 1):

```
x= ["6/1, 0, 0, ['79', '80', '81', '82']" ]
a=x[0].replace('\'','').split(', [')
finallist=a[0].split(',')
finallist.append(a[1].replace(']','').split(','))
print (finallist)
```

output

```
['6/1', ' 0', ' 0', ['79', ' 80', ' 81', ' 82']]
```

Comment: the inner list is still a string, no?

Comment: Ah I see what you are talking about, OP needs list of lists

Comment: I need to keep `['79', '80', '81', '82']` intact as list.

Comment: Awesome answer! that last part was tricky :-)  The only thing I might add for consistency (depending on the use case), would be to remove the preceding "spaces" in the numbers by adding `.replace(' ', '')` as in `finallist=a[0].replace(' ', '').split(',')` and `finallist.append(a[1].replace(' ', '').replace(']','').split(','))`